# How to change default text in "add to basket" button in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to change default button text "add to basket" in WooCommerce, in loop and in product page, using text field in customizer / Kirki:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'xx', 20, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'xx', 20, 3 );

// Kirki text field
$singleProductSimple = get_theme_mod( 'woo_cta_add_to_cart_simple', 'Dodaj do koszyka');

...

case 'simple':
  if ( class_exists('Polylang') ) {
    // for Polylang translation
    return pll_e( $singleProductSimple, 'behold-standard' );
  } else {
    // for WPML translation and just for the theme
    return _e( $singleProductSimple, 'behold-standard' );
  }
break;

...
```

It works ok only on product page, where new text is visible inside the button. In loop, custom text is visible above the button, and button is empty. How to fix it in loop?

Comment: It appears that pieces of code are missing (callback function, [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) when using case). 
Unless this is a specific syntax using Kirki?

Comment: No, it's not specific for Kirki, it's just a element of whole code, ofc there is a switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of "pll_e" should be "pll_", so problem solved :)